# TPL on Windows XP

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

We have a WPF app, where:

```
private void SomeHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Task.Factory.StartNew(LoadItems).ContinueWith(t =>
  {
    //cache items to, for instance, db
  }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);
}

private void LoadItems()
{
//sometimes it throws an exception
//this is expected
throw new FormatException("blablabla");
}
```

so, in general, We use this handler to try to cache the data when a data exists.
If it does not exist then we get a Formatexception. We don't care about the result, just "fire and forget" strategy.

I've got recently two log files from clients, where I saw that the FormatException was propagated to CurrentDomain_UnhandledException handler. All clients are on Windows XP with .Net 4.0.

So the question is why is it so? Is it as designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the expected behavior on .Net 4.0. If there is a `Task` with an exception and that exception is never observed, it's rethrown when the `Task` is finalized.

If you have .Net 4.5 installed and you want to get this behavior (for example for testing), [add `<ThrowUnobservedTaskExceptions>` to app.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj160346.aspx).

If you want to make sure unobserved `Task` exceptions aren't rethrown, even on .Net 4.0, you can use [`TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception):

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (o, args) => args.SetObserved();
```

But I think that the best option here is to explicitly observe the exception. You can do that by removing the `NotOnFaulted` option and checking the `Exception` property instead:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(LoadItems).ContinueWith(t =>
{
  if (t.Exception == null)
  {
    //cache items to, for instance, db
  }
});
```

Comment: Bearing in mind that if the continuation task also throws an exception that is never observed, you're straight back in the same boat :)

Comment: That is an interesting breaking change... Thanks for explaining

Comment: One more interesting observation, because exceptions are thrown in finalizers an application gets terminated even if a UnhandledException handlers were installed. This is what I see in the log of my app.